# How to implement confirm prompt default locale in node bot v4

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I am trying to do confirm prompt the user based on the user's prefered locale. but V4 bot prompting user in English as well eventhough Locale is spanish.

Here is my code in v4 node:

```
 const { ConfirmPrompt } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
    const CONFIRM_PROMPT_ES = 'confirmPrompt_ES';
    const CONFIRM_PROMPT_EN = 'confirmPrompt_EN';

// added dialogs to dialogSet

    this.addDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT_ES,false,**'es-mx'**))
                .addDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT_EN))



           if(constant.lang==='es'){
           console.log('---entered into spanish prompt block---');
             stepContext.context.activity.locale='es-mx';
           return await stepContext.prompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT_ES, { prompt: constant.liketostorevin }); 
       }
       else{
           console.log('---entered into english prompt block---');
            return await stepContext.prompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT_EN, { prompt: constant.liketostorevin });
       }
```

Please let me know if anyone know the way how to handle. thanks in advance.

Comment: can anyone please respond.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, of sorts, related to the locale value being passed in. Presently, the locale needs to be formatted as culture + locale and lowercase (e.g. 'fr-fr'). If you pass in only the culture or upper case locale (e.g. 'fr', 'FR', or 'en-FR'), then the prompt defaults to 'en-us'.

Make this adjustment, and you *should* be good to go. Please note, the defaultLocale option for ConfirmPrompt is **only** read if no locale is specified in the activity. Otherwise, it is ignored.

For reference, this was logged as an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1660) with a matching fix in [this](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/pull/1121) PR.

Hope of help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962636/steven-kanberg , As per ur answer, I have used lower case culture and locale still bot's confirm prompt appears in english. Please see updated code in my question . Please suggest where am I doing wrong. thanks for your time.

Comment: The issue is still tied to the culture-locale you are trying to pass thru. 'es-mx' isn't recognized (see ISO [639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)). Presently, [BotBuilder](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/prompts/choicePrompt.ts) matches on 'es-es' for Spanish. In the future, it will rely on Microsoft.Recognizers which also matches on 'es-es' for Spanish. Pass that thru and you should be good. Also, the `defaultLocale` is ONLY referenced IF the activity.locale is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

I made below changes to my code. Now bot able to prompt the confirmation as per locale.

```
var confPrompt=new ConfirmPrompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT_ES,false,'es-mx');
**confPrompt.confirmChoices= ['Sí', 'No']**

this.addDialog(confPrompt)
.addDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT_EN))

 return await stepContext.prompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT_ES, { prompt: constant.liketostorevin });
```

Hope this will be helpful to someone like me :)