# How can we set bot locale so that bot can prompt user based on its locale

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

How can we set bot locale in node v4. so that, bot can prompt user based on its locale.

in V#3 bot, if we set below value, bot can automatically prompt the user based on its locale. in V#4, how can we implement below logic.

```
in v#3:
session.preferredLocale(lang);

in v#4, how?

session.preferredLocale(lang);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to what value you are updating locale with. As I mention in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57655648) post, locale must be in the format of culture + locale and all lowercase (e.g. 'fr-fr). If you stray from that format, then the prompt defaults to 'en-us'.

There is a PR ([here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/pull/1121)) that addresses the formatting issue.

Hope of help!